# Setting for org-mode bullet font size

Tags: org-mode

I am using a custom theme (`doom-citylights`) and the size of the font for lines that are bullets in `org-mode` is a bit too big. Is there a variable I can set within my configuration to reduce this specific font size?

Comment: Are you talking about bullets as shown in the emacs buffer or when exported? If exported, to what export format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can set org headers sizes for display in your init.el/emacs.el like so:

```
(custom-set-faces
  '(org-level-1 ((t (:inherit outline-1 :height 2.0))))
  '(org-level-2 ((t (:inherit outline-2 :height 1.5))))
  '(org-level-3 ((t (:inherit outline-3 :height 1.2))))
  '(org-level-4 ((t (:inherit outline-4 :height 1.0))))
  '(org-level-5 ((t (:inherit outline-5 :height 1.0))))
)
```

these are just example sizes ( from pretty big to pretty small...)