# Can TODO headings in org mode inherit part of the heading style, specifically fontsize?

Tags: org-mode, faces, todo

Emacs initiate here, I've just now added different heading sizes for org-mode to my init file, according to the answer on this page: [Setting for org-mode bullet font size](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40505/setting-for-org-mode-bullet-font-size)

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(org-level-1 ((t (:inherit outline-1 :height 2.0))))
 '(org-level-2 ((t (:inherit outline-1 :height 1.8))))
 ;; etc...
 )
```

It works fine:

[image]

However, I've noticed that the styling for the TODO prefix doesn't take this into account, it just uses the default size.

[image] [image]

The DONE prefix even less so, as it applies styling to the *whole* heading. Obviously I'd prefer it if the whole heading had the same font-size, including TODO, DONE or other custom states. Is there a way to make the TODO prefixes scale alongside the rest of the heading?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this should already happen out of the box on a recent Org. Can you report what you get from `M-x org-version`?

Answer (score 0):

- for face of DONE heading, `(setq org-fontify-done-headline nil)` to make it inherit normal heading style. otherwise it uses face `org-headline-done`.
- sytles of todo keywords like TODO|DONE are controlled by `org-todo-keyword-faces`. Guess you cannot make 'em inherit the default heading style.

Answer (score 0):

TODOs styles have to be specified specifically. As an example, here is my config:

```lisp
* States
** States names:
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (setq org-todo-keywords
    '((sequence
       "INBOX(i)"
       "BACKLOG(b)"
       "NEXT(n)"      
       "MEETING(m)"
       "RECURRENT(r)"
       "STARTED(s)"
       "WAITING(w)"
       "DELEGATED(l)"
       "|"
       "DONE(d)"
       "DEFERRED(f)"
       "CANCELLED(c)"
  )))
#+END_SRC
** States colors & fonts (works best on night themes)
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (setq org-todo-keyword-faces '(
                 ("INBOX" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "#b8e4f9" :bold t :weight bold)) ; light blue
                 ("BACKLOG" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "#8d4eff" :bold t :weight bold)) ; light purple
                 ("RECURRENT" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "#ae81ff" :bold t :weight bold)) ; purple
                 ("NEXT" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "#ff84c9" :bold t :weight bold)) ; pink
                 ("STARTED" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "#ffa8d9" :bold t :weight bold)) ; light pink
                 ("DELEGATED" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "#f47b20" :bold t :weight bold)) ; orange
                 ("WAITING" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "#ffcc00" :bold t :weight bold)) ; yellow
                 ("MEETING" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "#00ffc0" :bold t :weight bold)) ; light green
                 ("DEFERRED" . ( :family "DejaVu Sans Mono":foreground "#4577d7" :bold t :weight bold)) ;blue
                 ("CANCELLED" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "gray55" :bold t :weight bold)) ; grey
                 ("DONE" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "gray65" :bold t :weight bold)) ; grey
                 ))
#+END_SRC
** Add a =CLOSED: [YYYY-MM-DD Day HH:MM]= line when the task is =DONE=
#+begin_src emacs-lisp 
(setq org-log-done 'time)
#+end_src
```

Headings styles can be configured at the theme level, especially if you use built-in `modus-themes`. Example:

```lisp
(use-package modus-themes
     :after (perfect-margin)
     :config
  (setq modus-themes-to-toggle
       '(modus-operandi-deuteranopia modus-vivendi-deuteranopia) ; Sets 2 themes from modus-themes-items
       modus-themes-common-palette-overrides; Override all modus-themes
       '((fg-heading-1 "RoyalBlue1"); Set Level 1 heading color
     (fg-heading-2 "SlateBlue1"); Set Level 2 heading color
     (fg-heading-3 blue-warmer); Set Level 3 heading color
     (fg-heading-4 blue); Set Level 4 heading color
     (fg-heading-5 cyan-warmer); Set Level 5 heading color
     (fg-heading-6 cyan-faint); Set Level 6 heading color
     (fg-heading-7 fg-dim); Set Level 7 heading color
     (fg-heading-8 pink); Set Level 8 heading color
     )
       modus-themes-headings
       '((1 . (1.4)); Set Level 1 heading size
         (2 . (1.3)); Set Level 2 heading size
         (3 . (1.2)); Set Level 3 heading size
         (4 . (1.1)); Set Level 4 heading size
         (t . (1.0))); Set Level 5 to 8 headings size
        )
  (load-theme 'modus-vivendi-deuteranopia :no-confirm)
  (define-key global-map (kbd "<f5>") #'modus-themes-toggle)
  )
```